# (x)html/css: list items distributed in columns

Tags: css, list, xhtml

Is there a way, with the help of CSS, to let a single list (ul or ol) behave like this:

```
1.    4.    7.
2.    5.    8.
3.    6.    9.
```

In other words, have their subsquent elements be distributed in columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using CSS3, you could always try using CSS3 multi-columns, also via [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/)

Comment: Aaahhh, good ol' A List Apart. Should have checked there first of course! :) Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A List Apart has a good [article on multi-column lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/).

There are no "pretty" ways to do this with CSS I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I would echo what [James Goodwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182768/james-goodwin) says, but include browser vendors experimental CSS support in your CSS:

```
ol {
    column-count:3;
    column-width:33%;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-width:33%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-width:33%;        
    /* etc., etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this by CSS but only by using HTML. Of course you could use a script language to create columns automatically, but CSS doesn't support this.

Comment: Hi Arno, thanks for the answer. "only by using HTML"? How so? You mean multiple <ul> or <ol>s I presume? If so; I was aiming for a solution that utilizes only one <ul> or <ol> element. If not, then could you elaborate on it a little? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I meant multiple list. I'm quiet sure it's the most comfortable way which works in every browser. You probably could try some CSS hacks--but I don't know any and would assume they don't work in every browser.